# ng-model input inside an angular-ui modal controller is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

In my modal template I'm trying to use `ng-model` to assign a value to the scope of my  controller (`$scope.name`), but it doesn't work. It gives me `undefined`. What am I doing wrong? [Plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/P4zEdJ8sW9ODzmCQ7IYu?p=preview)

I expect that the modal creates its own scope, and puts `name` into that scope because I used `ng-model`. It seems to be active inside the modal controller as I can output it fine using `{{name}}`

```
<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
        <div class="modal-body">
            Name: <input type="text" ng-model="name">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        </div>
    </script>
    <button class="btn" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {    
  $scope.open = function () {
    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl
    });
  };      
};

var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {    
  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.name);
    alert('name was: ' + $scope.name)
  };    
  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };      
};
```

Comment: You have missed the closed tag in the input field

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The model `name` is created inside a different scope. Use an object:

```
var ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
    $scope.data = {
        name:""
    };
    $scope.ok = function () {
        alert('name was: ' + $scope.data.name);
        $modalInstance.close($scope.data.name);
    };
```

<kbd>**[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/uN3yycW4FZgwWgXfcCYg?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks, can you explain why it works for an object and not for a normal variable?

Comment: By using a "dot", you are making AngularJS look up the prototype chain. Read more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716113