# ng-model with predefined select options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Ok, I'm sure this one is super simple, though it's evading me.

I have a very simple dropdown select menu - as shown below - with predefined options.

I am setting the `$scope.qty` in my controller and it correctly selects the appropriate `<option>`

However, in my controller, on a `save()` function, when I get the value of `$scope.qty` i get the original value, that i set earlier, and not the newly selected on.

What I am missing to bind my selected option to the model?

```
        <select ng-model="qty">
               <option value="1">1</option>
               <option value="2">2</option>
               <option value="3">3</option>
               <option value="4">4</option>
        </select>
```

In my controller, I set the qty

`$scope.qty = 4;`

When I change my select, to say 2, `$scope.qty` still equals 4.

Comment: you could use `ng-options` directive instead. I am sure it will work as expected.

Comment: yes, i could, though didn't want to have to put the options in the controller. In this case it's only ever going to be 1 to 4.

Comment: `ngModel` on `select` requires `ngOptions` to handle the case you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: [It works just fine.](http://jsfiddle.net/6C572/) It could be a problem of multiple $scopes.

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė - ok, now thats just weird! I have stripped my controller back to the same as yours - yet i still don't have the model set...

Comment: @KarolisJuodelė - THANK YOU! - I have this particular set of options loading in a modal using angular-ui modal. seems occasionally there will be a clash along the way - followed this for my fix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716113/scope-issue-in-angularjs-using-angularui-bootstrap-modal

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create the array in `ng-options`:

```
<select ng-options="nr for nr in [1,2,3,4]" ng-model="qty"></select>
```

Although the way you did it should usually work too. `ng-options` is not required for `ng-model` to work. It's the other way around.

Comment: god dammit... this is still doing the same.. I'll update my Q with all my code...

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS 1.3 only allows for a single option element that can be used for the null value (aka, not selected).

You need to use the ngOptions convention.

Here's the documentation that explains this:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select

Comment: That's not really relevant in my question or example code though - i have no `null` values and always have something selected. The issue was that my selection wasn't being bound to the scope - Karolis put me in the right direction on this and it's now fixed without having to add unnecessary objects to my scope

Comment: Sorry if I confused things by mentioning null values.  I meant to steer you towards using ngOptions for the option list.

I'm glad you got it working.