# Scope received in directive is not the same as the scope where directive really lives

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have this directive, which basically attaches a file to a model through `file-model="..."` (the entire purpose of this directive is because `ng-model` doesn't work in `<input type="file">` in angularjs)

```
angular.module('myApp').directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

            console.log(scope); // DEBUG

            var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);

            element.bind('change', function() {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    model.assign(scope, element[0].files[0]);
                });

                if (attrs.ngChange) {
                    scope.$apply(attrs.ngChange); 
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

And I also have a bootstrap-ui modal, **modal.html:**

```
<div class="modal-body">   
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" file-model="excelFile" ng-model="dummy" ng-change="uploadFile()" />
    </div>
</div>
```

With its corresponding bootstrap-ui controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('modalController', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', '$scope', function ($scope, $modalInstance, $scope) {

    $scope.uploadFile = function() {
        console.log($scope); // DEBUG

        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', $scope.excelFile); // empty!

        ...
    };
}]);
```

I invoke the modal from another controller like this:

```
$scope.openModal = function () {

    var modalScope = $scope.$new();

    modalScope.somePassedData = "I pass data this way";

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'views/modal.html',
        controller: 'modalController',
        scope: modalScope,
    });

    ...
};
```

So... if you notice the three comments:

1. First comment `// DEBUG`
2. Second comment `// DEBUG`
3. Comment `// empty!`

It seems that the scope used by the directive is not the same as the scope where the `<input type="file">` is living, and because of this I'm getting an empty file.

What am I doing wrong with scopes?

Also I should mention that this worked fine without using bootstrap ui-modal... so it must have something to do with the scope of the modal

Comment: The answer is here: `var modalScope = $scope.$new();`. `$scope.$new()` creates a new child scope that inherits from `$scope`. So anything in `$scope` should be in `modalScope` too. But you are saying that you "invoke the modal from another controller". Controllers have isolated scopes, so most likely `$scope.excelFile` is in another scope than `modalScope`, right?

Comment: You've seen [this related SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716113/scope-issue-in-angularjs-using-angularui-bootstrap-modal?rq=1) right, and you tried to initialize `$scope.input={}` and it didn't work?

Comment: Sorry I'm not following you... but I did tried to initialize $scope.excelFile in the scope of the modal

Comment: I read the link and it is not the case in here, because the passed scope is already initialized. The second "// DEBUG" is throwing a different scope from the first "// DEBUG". So my problem is not a null or undefined scope but a different one.

Answer (score 0):

Two things to test:

1. Verify that your `uploadFile` function is called **after** your directive's event handler (since they are listening to the same event). If it isn't, you should increase the priority of your `fileModel` directive to be greater than that of `ngChange` (which is 0).
2. Try using the `resolve` property to pass in data to your modal instead of creating a new scope. According to the documentation, `$modal` creates a child scope of the one you pass in, so you may be running into the prototypal inheritance issue with your primitive value.

Comment: Regarding (1): all the directive code is being called before the uploadFile() method (checked). Regarding (2): Hmm i will try, even though for all my modals in the past I have been passing a new scope from the parent