# Displaying a Modal Dialog in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-ui-utils

I am using AngularJS to develop an application. Below is my requirement is like:

1. User should have search screen to search batch information
2. once the result is loading, user is click on one of the batch
3. after opening a batch
4. When user click on Cancel batch, previous search screen should be open

I am using model dialogue to load search screen and also to display batch information. I am using model dialogue because in my batch information screen, lot of information is available.

This approach is suggested by the client. Please help me how to achieve this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) helps you to manipulate with modal dialogues.

Comment: Just go through the doc it has all what you need.

Answer (score -1):

1)

```
 Search: <input ng-model="query">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="object in OBJECTS| filter:query">
              {{object .name}}
            </li>
          </ul>
where OBJECTS iterable model in scope
this will show filtered li's
```

rest of your questions are not clear

Comment: Hi Biker, Thanks for reply. My requirement is like to display nested modal dialogue box. First dialogue box is for search screen and after search result when user click on any of the item in search, open another dialogue box. When user click on second dialogue box "cancel" button, first dialogue box is display.

Comment: In the controller of modal pass a function that will open new modal... and if are not comfortable with modal instance [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18716113/scope-issue-in-angularjs-using-angularui-bootstrap-modal)